# FileZilla is connecting to localhost instead of SSH server (can connect via PuTTY)

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, sftp, openssh

I have a Linux OS running on another machine in my home network, with an IP Address of 192.168.178.85. On this machine, I have installed OpenSSH and it is running on port 22.

I can SSH in using PuTTY on my Windows PC just fine. But when I try to connect to it via FileZilla, I get the following error:

```
Error:  Network error: Connection refused
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I have set it to connect via the SFTP protocol, and the host and username are entered correctly. How can I get FileZilla to connect via SFTP to the OpenSSH server?

Update: As requested, here are the PuTTY and FileZilla logs:

PuTTY:

```
2016-01-25 08:08:27 Looking up host "192.168.178.85"
2016-01-25 08:08:27 Connecting to 192.168.178.85 port 22
2016-01-25 08:08:27 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.65
2016-01-25 08:08:27 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4
2016-01-25 08:08:27 We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug
2016-01-25 08:08:27 Using SSH protocol version 2
2016-01-25 08:08:27 Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
2016-01-25 08:08:27 Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
2016-01-25 08:08:27 Host key fingerprint is:
2016-01-25 08:08:27 ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
2016-01-25 08:08:27 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
2016-01-25 08:08:27 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
2016-01-25 08:08:27 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
2016-01-25 08:08:27 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
```

FileZilla:

```
Command:    open "user@192.168.178.85" 22
Trace:  Looking up host "192.168.178.85"
Trace:  Connecting to ::1 port 9150
Trace:  We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Local:_Oct_16_2015_12:02:11
Trace:  Failed to connect to ::1: Network error: Connection refused
```

From the looks of it, FileZilla seems to forget the IP address it's trying to connect to and instead tries to connect to ::1 port 9150 instead?

Update 2: I tried another SFTP client, WinSCP, and it is working perfectly with the OpenSSH server, so it must be an issue with FileZilla. I don't know whats causing the issue with FileZilla but it seems like just switching clients is my best bet.

Comment: it depends what linux os distribution you are using. What was the path to sftp subsystem before you changed it? Does the file exists? What were the errors in server log? If you have Debian based distro, you need to install `openssh-sftp-server` also!

Comment: I tried installing openssh-sftp-server but it was already installed. In the sshd_config file, the sftp subsystem line was "Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server". Assuming you mean /var/log/auth.log, I don't see anything other than sudo session closed messages. I'm using Xubuntu

Comment: You should try to check the error messages on the Linux machine.

Comment: based on the description, it should Just work. So I would recommend you to double-check IPs, username, password, port. If it will not help, you can create [verbose logs from filezilla](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Logs#Changing_the_verbosity). If you really connect to the machine, there should be record in the `auth.log`. Also providing how does your `sshd_config` look like (eg. what have you changed) might help.

Comment: Show us Event log from PuTTY (right click its window title) and FileZilla log file (a real log file, not message log from GUI).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Here is the putty log: http://pastebin.com/dZxxbvqU. Here is a verbose log from Filezilla: http://pastebin.com/MsJtr3s5. As of this comment I have not modified the original sshd_config file (I did edit the Subsystem line as per the answer below, but reverted it when it did not work)

Answer (score 0):

The FileZilla does not even try to connect to the server. It connects to a local host to port 9150:

> Connecting to ::1 port 9150

I assume it tries to use a [connection sharing function of PuTTY](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-sharing) (FileZilla shares an SSH code with PuTTY).

The connection sharing seems to fail for some reason.

And you probably do not want that anyway. As it will make FileZilla use PuTTY's SSH connection, which is not optimized for bulk transfers.

Disable the *Share SSH connections is possible* in PuTTY to avoid this happening (it's disabled by default, you must have enabled it).

---

*Anyway, using WinSCP is your best bet :) (I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Off topic, but I use WinSCP loads so thank you very much.